# How to make a div scroll area with the remaining height

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I want to fill in the rest of the space on the page and have the scrollbar right next to the content instead of at the edge of the page.

I'm trying to accoplish this using `overflow-y:scroll;width:100%;`, but it's not working

It's a bit hard to explain so here's a plunk:
https://plnkr.co/edit/F2w3JZNxjoMJpxSCzGFM?p=preview 
The goal is to have the scrollbar on the page handle the scrolling not the one at the edge of the page

Comment: Check this may you want something like https://plnkr.co/edit/9WA3YqaMk4LBXBaSV0EE?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your page to be a full-screen app with only the `.content` section scrollable, you can use a combination of CSS flexbox and viewport units to achieve that (see second solution if you are concerned about flexbox support).

1. Wrap your content in a wrapper, say `<div class="wrapper">`
2. Set the wrapper's height to `100vh` (100% of viewport height), and use `display: flex` and set the flex-direction to `column`.
3. Ensure that `flex-shrink` is set to `0` on the `.header`, because we don't want it to collapse in height.

This will ensure that `.content` will grow as of when needed to fill up the remaining vertical space on the viewport that is left unoccupied by the `.header`. See proof-of-concept below:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  position:relative;
  height:112px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.content {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

An alternative solution to using CSS flexbox is simply to use CSS `calc`, but that leverages on support for the `calc()` method:

1. `.content` height should simply be `calc(100vh - <headerHeight>)`, which will be `calc(100vh - 112px)` for your case.
2. Remember to use `box-sizing: border-box` on the `.header` element, so that the declared height will take into account the border.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  position:relative;
  height:112px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  
  /* Use border-box so that borders are taken into height declaration */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height: calc(100vh - 112px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```